# Bluetooth keyboard connects, but does not work

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, input, hid

I have a Lenovo Duet 3 Bluetooth keyboard, which works fine when connected physically (it has 5 pins for that) to its laptop, and also works as expected when I connect it to my Android phone.

However, I cannot get it to work under (Arch) Linux. Kernel and bluetooth stack (bluez-libs etc.) are up to date, so I connect the device using `bluetoothctl` (output abbreviated for clarity):

```
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[NEW] Device D6:45:02:72:41:4F Duet 3 BT
[bluetooth]# pair D6:45:02:72:41:4F
Attempting to pair with D6:45:02:72:41:4F
[CHG] Device D6:45:02:72:41:4F Connected: yes
[CHG] Device D6:45:02:72:41:4F ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device D6:45:02:72:41:4F Paired: yes
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D6_45_02_72_41_4F/service000a
    00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Generic Attribute Profile
    ... {more new services follow, e.g. for Dev. Information, Battery etc.}
Pairing successful
[Duet 3 BT]# trust D6:45:02:72:41:4F
Changing D6:45:02:72:41:4F trust succeeded
[Duet 3 BT]# connect D6:45:02:72:41:4F
Attempting to connect to D6:45:02:72:41:4F
Connection successful
[Lenovo Duet 3 BT Folio]#
```

The device stays connected, and I can see battery information. So far, so good, but typing anything or using the trackpad does absolutely nothing, so it's pretty useless as an input device.

Comment: Can confirm the exact same behavior with a "Duet 3 BT Folio" keyboard on Debian Testing/Bookworm, kernel 5.17.0-1 at the moment. Haven't gotten any further than you, unfortunately 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to turn on Caps Lock before you detach the keyboard.

Comment: Can you explain why this might work? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Strangely enough, this does work. The Trackpad  and mouse keys still don't work, but the keyboard functions well, including switching off Caps Lock.
Maybe it's a quirk in the driver, or maybe in the keyboard's firmware itself, hard to say.

Comment: I undertook some more experiments.
- It also works with NumLock.
- Since the keyboard works fine with my phone, it's probably a quirk in Linux' bluetooth stack. I supspect it's related to sending a non-zero value for the Num/Caps/Scroll lock indicators.